# how to color many references in bibliography in latex

Tags: latex, bibtex

I have different citations like article, book etc in my .bib file. How can I color continuous citation items in red?

```
@Article{article1,
AUTHOR = ...
}
@Article{article2,
AUTHOR = ...
}
...
```

So I would like that article1, article2 and whatever comes after article2 become red in the list of references.

```
\textcolor{\red}{...} doesn't work in .bib file
```

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/188127/color-text-in-bibliography-text

Comment: Also related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/225218/how-to-change-the-color-of-bibitems?rq=1